# Strong solutions to PDEs

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $(E)$ be the equation :

$$\partial _t u + (u \cdot \nabla_x) u + \nabla _x p = \Delta _x u $$ with $\nabla \cdot u =0$ where $f: [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ (Navier-Stokes equations)

Generally $u$ is sait to be a strong solution when $u$ belongs to $C^1([0,T],H^1(\mathbb{R}^3))$ which implicitly means that $u$ is viewed as a function $u : t \in [0,T] \mapsto u(t) \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^3) $.

In my opinion a strong solution should be a $u : [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying $\mapsto u(t, \cdot ) \in H^1$ for all $t$ and $u(\cdot , x) \in C^1$ for all $x$.

Is there a link between these two définitions ? Intuitively there are the same but I am not able to prove this (I considered the function $F : (t,x) \mapsto u (t)(x)$ for exemple)

If you have experienced this question please tell me what do I hold back of this question and if there is documents on the internet explaining it.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on this subject of "mixed" spaces, but I think they are not only not the same but not even one is stronger than the other. The first one says that at each time, $u$ is a $H^1$ function of $x$, and in a short time, the whole function $u$ does not change very much in the $H^1$ norm. The second one says that at each time, $u$ is an $H^1$ function of $x$, and in a short time, $u$ does not change much at each point $x$. But since $H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ doesn't embed into $C^0(\mathbb{R}^3)$, point evaluation is not continuous in $H^1$, so these are distinct notions.

Comment: Thank you for considering the question. In fact the second definition is not well defined, but only defined almost everywhere ... if you have good references about mixes spaces I would take them !

Comment: Have you gone through Evans already? This is discussed in some detail there. Also, the second definition *is* well defined but it probably assumes more regularity about $u(\cdot,x)$ than you want to assume in this setting. That kind of regularity is indeed what you get in, say, the heat equation.

Comment: I've never got through Evans (you are refering to "Partial Differential Equations" ?), I will try to ! Still for my example, it is an arbitrary one, not wisely chosen, you might replace it with what you want if it bothers you ^^